# How can i write a code to send an email on submit using Ruby Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to rails and i have a TEST.
I just installed and seted up everything needed to lunch the application,
I do have an existing app and i need to modify and write a simple send email code on click,

Here is the code:

```
<%= form_tag root_path, class: "send-email" do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Click to Send Email", style: "margin: 10px; padding: 10px" %>
<% end %>

<script>
document.querySelector(".send-email").onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  fetch(e.target.action, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
      window.open('/mail', '_blank')
    } else {
      console.error(response)
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

I would highly appriciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at the docs for the ActionMailer (which is an emailing interface for Ruby on Rails framework): https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

1. generate mailer using rails cli command

```bash
$ bin/rails generate mailer User
```

2. edit generated `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email
    @user = params[:user]
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

3. edit your  `app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb` or text version if you prefer

```rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.login %>.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

4. hook it up with your Controller/correct route that triggers email send. refer this section https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#calling-the-mailer
   and this for routes https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
   in your example your button points to the `root_path` and this needs to change to the path that points to a correct Controller with this email action(a controller that linked to the view code you wrote in your example)
   if View / Controller terms do not make sence - consider reading about MVC pattern: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-model-view-controller-pattern-mvc-architecture-and-frameworks-explained/